# How to create multi-select in angular-js like django admin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, django

I want to create multi-select like in django admin for database. Here in one box it will show all available items and other box show all selected items. When I select any items and **click on it** it will go other selected box. Following we have to click on arrow but I do not it, but click on item itself.

In following demo,

```
1. I want to add search box as in djano-admin for search items.   
2. It should be swap to other box when you click on item itself, but not at arrow.
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/f6LEpeqldPMCjyvXytnv?p=preview

[image]